# What is the power consumption of an amplifier while powering a pair of speakers?

Tags: amplifier, speakers, power-consumption

I need help getting power consumption to pick the right battery for a portable sound contraption.

I have an amplifier with the following specifications:

- Class D
- 100 W MAX Power Output X 2 (4 ohms, 20 Hz - 20 kHz, 0.04% THD)
- 24V power supply - can drive 200 watts (8 ohm), 300 watts (4 ohm); Output power: 100W + 100W
- Power supply voltage range: 15v-24v
- Power supply RMS range: 90w - 120w
- Input sensitivity: ≤ 280mV;
- Terminating impedance: 2Ohm - 8Ohm;

I am powering a pair of speakers with these specs:

- 180 watts MAX per 90 watts RMS power handling per pair (4 ohm)
- 80 Hz to 20 kHz
- Frequency Response 89 dB Sensitivity

I am wondering what is the power consumption of the amplifier when I have the volume half the way up? How does the power consumption changes when I power it up to 3/4?

Comment: Measure. Guesses can easily be off by a factor of 5 or 10 here and a volume of 3/4 (or turning it up to 11 for that matter) don't tell us anything about the real average power.

Comment: Average power will be much less than peak. It also depends what you're playing! Bass-heavy music will require more power since it has to move more air.

Comment: There is no way to answer this. We can't possibly know how much it will consume as we don't know what material you are playing and how the volume pot affects the signal in which position.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have the amplifier it should be easy to find some speakers to test it with and make some current measurements. You haven't specified what the amplifier's type is and power consumption will vary by Class A, B and D (the most popular).

Once you have the current consumption multiply that by the desired run time to get the required Ah capacity (and multiply that by 1.5 to 2 safety margin to specify the battery).

Answer (score 1):

Amplifier sellers lie about output power.

With a 24V supply, a TPA3116 chip produces 60W per channel into 4 ohm speakers with low distortion. AliExpress says 120W x 2 (240W) but they say the 24V current is only 3A (72W). So the 240W is a lie.
Since the class-D amplifier heats a little then extra current is needed, use 24V at 6A. But music and speech are not continuously full blast so the average current will be less.

The maximum undistorted power can be produced when the volume control is set low or maybe can never be reached when the volume control is set to maximum. It depends on the loudness of the input signal and the amount of gain for the amplifier.

A volume control is not linear (half setting for half power), instead it is logarithmic like our hearing's sensitivity. Half the power is only a little less loud, 1/10th the power sounds half as loud.

Answer (score 0):

If have you a laptop charger 19.5V 65W to 120W, that should be adequate as long as the supply noise isn't an issue. You may have to put an RF cap to PE ground .

If you have efficient 12" speakers in a large cabinet that are 92dB @ 1m @ 1W without crossovers, that will be more than enough .  If you have a sub-woofer channel that's a bonus.

Otherwise, it's an inexpensive starting point.

Reading your specs now,;) I think you may be pleased with the outcome. But long term dynamic load swings on these types of supplies don't tend to last more than a few years if they run warm on the outside and hot on the inside, so keep everything as cool as possible even with a low speed CPU fan if necessary or 2 in series.  caps wear out 2x as fast every 10°C rise.